# viewController.view not getting added to custom view inside Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to add a childViewController into a custom UIView part of a parentViewController. However, if I am doing `self.customView.addSubview(childViewController.view)` I cannot see the `childViewController.view` as it doesn't get added. In contrast, if I do `self.view.addSubview(childViewController.view)` it all works well. Can someone explain why this is happening? I really need to add childViewController.view as subview of the customView and not as part of the `self.view`.

```
if let childViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVC") as UIViewController? {
            self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
            childViewController.view.frame = customView.bounds
            self.customView.addSubview(childViewController.view)
            childViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            childViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: customView.frame.origin.x,
                                         y: customView.frame.origin.y,
                                         width: customView.frame.width,
                                         height: customView.frame.height)

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]How about using a  **Container view** from Object Library (place from where we drag table view, textView and all UI components onto our storyboard). which is

> **Container view** define a region of view controller that include 
>   a child view controller

- When you take **Container view** from object library in your desired
  ViewController on storyBoard.
- it automatically gives you a another view controller attached to your view controller with a segue.
- you just need to override this segue code and that dragged container view will work as a child view controller for you it did load will call automatically.

just Override this is your parent view Controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
      switch identifier {
      case "SegueIndetifierName":
        (segue.destination as? YourChildViewController)?.parentViewControllerObject = self
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

**NOTE:** declare parentView controller object in your child view controller like this

```
weak var parentViewControllerObject: ParentViewController!
```

to uniquely identify the relation ship between child and parent. and rest your work will be done automatically.

Comment: yes, using a container view worked. So then the conclusion would be that a when adding a uiviewcontroller as a child inside a parentuiviewcontroller, one would need a containerviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Sample Working project to add Subviews

Link https://github.com/RockinGarg/Container_Views.git

Required Code:

**Class Object to be added as Subview**

```
private lazy var FirstObject: firstVC =
  {
    // Instantiate View Controller
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC") as! firstVC

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.addChildViewController(viewController)
    return viewController
  }()
```

**Add in ParentView as Subview**

```
private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController)
{
    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.firstContainer.frame.size.width, height: self.firstContainer.frame.size.height)

    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(viewController)
    viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    // Add Child View as Subview
    firstContainer.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Where : -

`firstContainer` is the parent view In which subview is to be added

`viewController` class object whose view is to be added as Subview

**Note-** This can be used in containerViews as well as Normal UIView too for adding a Controller as Subview

Comment: this is another great answer. I went with the one above though. It best suited my case